# Legacy Finance package

Tags: packages, finance

There used to be an old package `Finance` which contained useful functionality for converting between different interest rate representations, `SpotRates`, `ForwardRates`, and `DiscountFactors` among other useful things:

https://reference.wolfram.com/applications/finance/InterestRates.html

Does anyone know how to access these functionalities in the current version of Wolfram or where to find and install this legacy package?

Answer (score 1):

In 13.2 on Windows 10 the first example from the link can be reproduced as follows (If I am not mistaken.).

```
TimeValue[100000,EffectiveInterest[.0726,1/365],300/365]
```

> `106148.`

Comment: My main interest is the interest rate conversions.